# Update UI after applying ko.utils.arrayFilter

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following snippet of code. I am trying to filter the array `viewModel.customers` and update the UI. However, the UI is not updated and I don't see any errors. As a note: all the properties of the array are observable. Tee below code is a small snipped of a much larger view model.

```
<div class="row" data-bind="visible: customers().length > 0">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-offset-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter Result"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-bind="click: filterCustomers">Filter</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var viewModel = {
    PageName: "Editor",                
    textFilter: ko.observable(), // property to store the filter                
    customers: ko.observableArray([]),              
};    

 viewModel.filterCustomers= function() {
     return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.customers(), function (item) {                  
        return item.CustomerNumber().toLowerCase() === viewModel.textFilter().toLowerCase();
     });
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrayFilter returns a new filtered array. It doesn't alter the original array. You'll have to do something with the result, either update your original array or create another observable to hold the new array so that it can be displayed.

```
viewModel.filteredCustomers = ko.observableArray([]);

viewModel.filterCustomers = function() {
     viewModel.filteredCustomers(ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.customers(), function (item) {                  
        return item.CustomerNumber().toLowerCase() === viewModel.textFilter().toLowerCase();
     }));
 };
```